# AngularJs data access Levels

Tags: angularjs, navbar, data-access

I am trying to make a application in springMvc, velocity with html pages and angularJs for ticket booking. This is my first time to use angularJs.

**NavBar**

```
Home | Application Setting | Travel | Bulk Booking | Users | Profile | Announcements | Support Mgmt | Support
```

**3 user groups**

```
 1. Admin. 
 2. Normal Users. 
 3. Agents (with some extra access then Normal).
```

**Access Levels**

```
- Admin - Home, Application Settings , Users, Announcements, Support Mgmt, Profile
- Agent - Home, Bulk Booking, Support, Profile
- Normal Users - Home, Travel, Support,Profile
```

How to do this with ng-view. Please just point me in right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to learn AngularJS? Or Spring MVC? or make app?
If you trying to accomplish all 3 tasks you go nowhere.

Comment: I am trying to make a springMvc app with Angular. I know spring but i am new in angularJs.

Comment: read up on $routeProvider: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: the tutorial in the angular docs will explain it for you. SPend the time to go through each stage it is well worth it

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful: [Authentication in Single Page Applications With Angular.js](http://www.frederiknakstad.com/2013/01/21/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/)

directives.js does updateCSS() if user has group (access level is a bitmap of groups) thus showing/hiding menu item.

Menu item would look like
`<li data-access-level="accessLevels.admin">`

routingConfig.js holds logic "if user has access based on his groups".